# Cosmos DB Stored procedure did not execute without PartitionKey

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a collection which has PartitionKey.i have a made a stored procedure which accepts query as a parameter. in this stored procedure, I'm fetching some documents to update but while fetching it shows an error saying provide PartitionKey when I use the method

```
public Task<StoredProcedureResponse<TValue>> ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<TValue>(Uri storedProcedureUri, [Dynamic(new[] { false, true })] params dynamic[] procedureParams);
```

while using the other method

```
public Task<StoredProcedureResponse<TValue>> ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<TValue>(string storedProcedureLink, RequestOptions options, [Dynamic(new[] { false, true })] params dynamic[] procedureParams);
```

in this method, I have Pass the PartitionKey as

```
new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(Undefined.Value)
```

while using this RequestOptions in the Stored Procedure no Document is Fetch.

```
function ABC(query) {
var collection = getContext().getCollection();
var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();
var response = getContext().getResponse();
// Validate input.
if (!query) throw new Error("The query is undefined or null.");

tryQueryAndDelete();

function tryQueryAndDelete(continuation) {
    var requestOptions = { continuation: continuation };

    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(collectionLink, query, requestOptions, function (err, retrievedDocs, responseOptions) {
        if (err) throw err;

        if (retrievedDocs.length > 0) {
           console.log("Doc Found");
        } else {
           console.log("Doc not Found");

        }
    });
}
```

}

is there anyway so that I can fetch the documents without passing the PartitionKey?

Comment: Hi,any updates now?

Comment: As per ur suggestion in the chat, I have to fetch all the documents, update the Properties then save it again each documents partition key and it works in this way.@JayGong

Comment: Great! You could mark the answer for others' reference. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the collection the stored procedure is registered against is a
>   single-partition collection, then the transaction is scoped to all the
>   documents within the collection. If the collection is partitioned,
>   then stored procedures are executed in the transaction scope of a
>   single partition key. Each stored procedure execution must then
>   include a partition key value corresponding to the scope the
>   transaction must run under.

You could refer to the description above which mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming#database-program-transactions).

It's impossible to escape the above rule by setting the partition-key to `Undefined.Value`. You must provide the partition key when you execute stored procedure in partitioned collection.

> is there anyway so that I can fetch the documents without passing the
>   PartitionKey?

You could set `EnableCrossPartitionQuery` to `true` in FeedOptions parameter when executing query sql.(has performance bottleneck).

Hope it helps you.

Comment: did not find any overridden method for ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync which take FeedOptions.  do I need to pass the EnableCrossPartitionQuery to true in the stored procedure requestOptions? @jay Gong

Comment: @SatyaraySingh no no, EnableCrossPartitionQuery is one property in FeedOptions,not RequestOptions. So,you have to provide partition key with executing stored procedure anyway.

Comment: there are 4 override methods ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync in DocumentClient class to Execute the stored procedure but none of them have FeedOptions as parameters. is that Simply means I can't do that in store procedure? @jay Gong

Comment: @SatyaraySingh Yes. you don't have any routes to get the partition key?

Comment: the Documents which I'm trying to fetch all have a different partition key. I think I need to fetch all the document in code then update it after that I will save it individually. @jay Gong

Comment: @SatyaraySingh Let's talk in this chat room:https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169914/jay-satyaray-singh

Comment: @SatyaraySingh Sorry for the delay message ,please check the chat room again .Thx.

Comment: @JayGong is there a way to create unpartitioned collection? and btw the link is not valid any more:(

Comment: @fascynacja Surely,you have to create unpartitioned collection by sdk,not on the portal. I searched just now,but i can't find any statement at the creation tag of cosmos db on the portal. I remember there is a suggestion for you over there. Anyway , do it in sdk. Don't set partition key when you create collection in sdk.